# Can't select schedule

Tags: schedule, automationanywhere

I use automation anywhere.
I want to use schedule manager, so I read this document.

https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/working-with-automation-tasks/using-the-schedule-manager.html

My schedule select only one time.

My AA do not show other Task.(everyday,everymonth etc...)

If you know how to solve this problem, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because you are using creator account, to use these options login with runner account.